# How to find the Thévenin voltage?

Tags: thevenin

How do I find the Thévenin voltage in this diagram?

In parallel the voltage remains the same, so should it be 10 volts across AB?

I am given that since \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ are not connected on one end, they do not carry current. Therefore, they cannot have a voltage drop. The voltage present between points A and B is the voltage drop across \$R_2\$.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: thats not homework!As the image shows I am trying to learn from a website.Anyhow thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia has very nice article about [Thévenin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Thévenin equivalent consists of a single voltage source in series with a single resistor, together between points A and B. To find the voltage of the voltage source and the resistor value you consider two different load situations.

**1.**
**No load** at all, like it's drawn. The circuit consists of voltage source, R1, R2 and R5. There's no current through R3 or R4. We calculate the current: \$\dfrac{V+}{R1+R2+R5}=\dfrac{10V}{3k + 4k + 3k}=1mA\$. Then the voltage over R2 is 1mA * 4k = 4V, and since there's no voltage drop over R3 or R4 that's also the voltage between A and B.
In the Thévenin equivalent, when A-B is open there won't flow any current, so no voltage drop over the internal resistor. If we want 4V between A and B, the voltage source has to be 4V.

**2.**
**Short-circuit** A and B. Now R2 is parallel to the series resistance of R3 and R4. We need to know the equivalent of these (call it R6): \$\dfrac{1}{R6}=\dfrac{1}{R2}+\dfrac{1}{R3+R4}=\dfrac{1}{4k}+\dfrac{1}{6k}=\dfrac{0.417}{1k}\$ so \$R6=\dfrac{1k}{0.417}=2k4\$.
Again we calculate the current: \$\dfrac{V+}{R1+R6+R5}=\dfrac{10V}{3k + 2k4 + 3k}=1.19mA\$. The voltage over R6 is \$10V - 1.19mA \times (R1 + R5) = 2.85V\$, hence the current through R3 and R4 (and the short-circuit A-B) is \$\dfrac{2.85V}{R3 + R4}=\dfrac{2.85V}{6k}=476\mu A\$.
Our Thévenin circuit had a voltage source of 4V. To have 476\$\mu\$A through a short-circuited A-B the internal resistance has to be \$\dfrac{4V}{476\mu A}=8k4\$.

And that's our solution:

> Equivalent voltage = 4V,
>   Equivalent series resistance = 8k4

Comment: @Federico - True, but I find this makes more sense :-)

Comment: @ stevenh: Agreed with everything, but found your answer notation confusing.  I thought, by "8k4," you meant 80k.  I see now that you meant 8.4K.

Comment: @Vintage - The scaling prefix/infix notation was covered in [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7586/in-the-middle-of-a-capacitor-rating/7591#7591).

Answer (score 2):

For Rth，first short the power supply of 10V, then calculate resistance.
R1 is in series with R5, 3k+3k=6k, the result is in parallel with R2 => 6k || 4k = (6k x 4k )/(6k+4K)=2k4, then that is in series with R3 and R4.
2k4+3k+3k=8k4.