# µ in the Middle of a Capacitor Rating

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, ratings

I'm looking at an electrolytic capacitor (and old blue, Philips one used in electronics classes) and am wondering why it is printed with **4µ7-M**.

I tried Googling, figuring that it was a common enough occurrence, but found nothing.

Is that supposed to be a 47µF cap? Why is the µ in the middle of the number? What is the -M for?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not sure I have seen this before (although the answers do seem vaguely familiar). The explanations for it also make sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "µ" symbol is put in place of the decimal point, 4µ7 translates to 4.7 µ farads.

Not too sure about the "-M" part tho - sorry

Comment: This is correct. You will also see this on some resistors were it will say 4k2 and mean 4.2k ohm.

Comment: I suspect the M is probably some kind of indication of the dielectric temperature characteristic or voltage rating. It's probably a manufacturer specific code.

Comment: The "M" stands for tolerance code.

J = +/-5%
K = +/-10%
M = +/-20%

Answer (score 8):

Like Jim said, the µ indicates the place of the decimal point. This isn't restricted to capacitors, but also used for resistors and inductors:

> resistor 31k6 = 31.6 kiloOhm
>   resistor 5M6 = 5.6 megaOhm
>   capacitor 2n2 = 2.2 nanoFarad
>   inductor 4µ7 = 4.7 microHenry

Comment: Beware people who use m for mega- and M for milli-.  Not always that difficult to distinguish, but harder than (capital) S for seconds people.

Comment: Good point, but most of the time this can be derived from context; 1m0 on an inductor will be milli rather than mega :-)

Comment: Most circuit simulation packages will also accept this format, but beware that they may not be case-sensitive, so a "1M0" resistor could work out as a 1.0 milliohm resistor, so use 1Meg in this case.

Comment: It gets even worse... Have you ever heard of a 100 uuF cap? That's micro-micro-farads. Nowadays, we call them picofarads.

Answer (score 5):

It caused less confusion than sometimes arose with a decimal point, which was missed sometimes when documents were copied or faxed. That's not such a problem these days, but it is in common use, especially here in Europe. I always use that notation.

Comment: I was more thinking about markings on components than documents, but you're right. However, in SMD markings a decimal point gets lost even more easily.

Comment: And in some European countries, a comma is used instead of a decimal point for the seperation of the fractional part, and a point is used for seperating out the thousand part instead of a comma.

Comment: @Martin: in everyday use the comma is used in all of Europe, except for the UK. But I've never seen it on components