# What does "5k1" in the given schematic mean?

Tags: resistors

What does the "5k1" stands for it is a normal 5k Ohm resistor?

(Marked with "A" in the picture)

The chip is an [MAX13020](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX13020-MAX13021.pdf) LIN-transceiver.

[image: Schematic with markes question]

Comment: It means a \$5.1 \text{ k}\Omega\$ resistor

Comment: @ThePhoton if you do not know what it stand for you don't find the duplicate (it did noch show up)

Comment: There's no reason you would have known. Nonetheless, the question is a duplicate. We can't have 10,000 different questions like "What does 2k11 stand for?", "What does 4R7 stand for?" and so on for every standard resistor value.

Comment: @ThePhoton I know all right

Comment: So-many possible duplicates: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246920/what-is-a-100r-resistor

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28053/what-does-3v3-or-1v8-mean

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45272/resistor-value-labeling-what-does-the-second-number-refer-to

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166100/what-does-0-025r-or-30r-mean-here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resistors are often marked using the letter k (or letter M) instead of the decimal separator, so 5k1 means 5.1k\$\Omega\$ or 5100\$\Omega\$, while for example 1M2 means 1.2M\$\Omega\$.

A unique letter for each type of element can substitute for a decimal point in small values. For example, 6R8 is used to indicate a 6.8 \$\Omega\$ resistor. Similarly, the letter V substitutes for a decimal point in voltages such as 3V3 for 3.3 volts.

That same marking style is often used on ceramic or polyester capacitors, where for example "2n2" stands for 2.2nF.

About the diode, that's not just a B, there's written "BAT46" that is a specific kind of diode. A datasheet from Vishay can be found [here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/85662/bat46.pdf).

Comment: If you don't mind - I've improved your answer with info about 6R8 notation for 6.8\$\Omega\$.

Comment: Well IIRC, R is not here because it's the first letter of "resistor" but because it's the first letter of "Radix point" (decimal point)

Comment: @VladimirCravero the red "B" stands for question B ;) But you should not ask more than one question in one post so i did not ask it directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is shorthand for 5.1K, where the K takes the place of the decimal. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/Resistors#Identification

Comment: ok and "B" (bat 46) stands for a normal diode? I coud also ask this in an other question but if someone can answer it here it would be good.

Comment: It looks like BAT46 to me, which is a part number you can look up (on Findchips or Octopart, for example).

Comment: they're referring to a specific part: http://www.vishay.com/docs/85662/bat46.pdf

Comment: ok, that was all I was looking for!