# What is a "100R" resistor?

Tags: resistors, schematics, symbol, math-notation

Sometimes I see references to "R" resistors. For example:

[image]

Obviously the 100 refers to 100 Ohms. What does 100R mean?

Comment: The R is sometimes used as a decimal point. So 100R is 100 Ohms, 4R7 is 4.7 Ohms, etc.

Comment: " Radix point "

Comment: Traditional ascii fonts do not have an omega symbol, so 'R' is commonly used instead.

Comment: @pjc50 Once I was working with a US student and a Canadian postdoc.  The postdoc kept saying "zed" instead of "z", and eventually the student asked "What's a zed?"  I told her it was a backwards z, but since we didn't have those on our standard keyboards, we would just type "z"

Comment: @pjc50 Technically the ohm sign, Ω (U+2126) is not a greek capital omega, Ω (U+03A9), though in many fonts they are represented by identical glyphs

Comment: @bcrist: Just because Unicode has a separate code point for "Ohm" (which is silly) does NOT mean that it is not a capital Omega.

Comment: @bcrist Note that Unicode 4.0 states the Ohm symbol is only for backwards compatibility, and explicitly discourages its use in favor of Greek capital omega (see bottom of p. 176 http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode4.0.0/ch07.pdf)

Comment: Not mentioned in any of the answers below but the use of R is standardized in BS 1852 and it's successors. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1852)

Comment: @JasonC You should really add that to the accepted answer. It is useful information and here in the comments it will get lost (comments are transient).

Comment: On a tiny SMD part, try to not confuse "4.7" with "47", and "4Ω7" not with "407".

Comment: @ScottSeidman  "Z" ("Zee"?) is called "Zed" in UK English, and Some of its derivatives such as in India. So-far I know, Zed and Zee are the same thing. Btw I never seen use of Z in resistor value.

Comment: Wikipedia tells : The European notation BS 1852 avoids using a decimal separator ... problem that decimal separators tend to **"disappear" when photocopying** a printed circuit diagram. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Electronic_symbols_and_notation

Comment: Have seen use of E for ohm also . such as 5E6, 56E, 47E etc.

Comment: so-many opinion-based (at-least partly) informations are possible.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused -- yes -- I was joking around with the student

Comment: @ScottSeidman ok however I couldn't found relevance of "Z" to the OP. Looks off-topic to me.

Comment: There are many possible duplicates of this question that proves it is an wide problem.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166100/what-does-0-025r-or-30r-mean-here

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45272/resistor-value-labeling-what-does-the-second-number-refer-to

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107698/what-does-5k1-in-the-given-schematic-mean

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28053/what-does-3v3-or-1v8-mean

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The idea is that the multiplier replaces the decimal point. This dates back to pre-CAD schematics which were hand drawn and then photocopied and reduced. A decimal point could easily get lost during the copying process. By writing 4k7 rather than 4.7k the risk of these errors was greatly reduced. R was used for a multiplyer of 1 because omega could easily be mistaken for a 0. So ... 4R7, 47R, 470R, 4k7, 47k, 470k, 4M7, 47M.

The same approach is used with capacitors: 2p2, 22p, 220p, 2n2, 22n, 220n, 2u2, 22u, 220u. In the old days larger values were still marked µF so the next decade was marked 2200u but with large capacitor values common now we're seeing 2m2, 22m, etc. I've never seen an equivalent of the 'R' as in 2C2 for a 2.2 F - yet! 2F2 may be more sensible. The current use of 'R' would then be excused (4R7 instead of 4Ω7) on the basis that Ω isn't readily available on most keyboards.

This system may be more popular in Europe.

---

Thanks to @JasonC for pointing out that the 'R' notation is covered by British Standard [BS 1852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1852).

Comment: And if you stare at the R for long, it sort of looks like someone got a stretchy omega and pinched its center to join the two legs, and moved it up and to the left a bit.

Comment: Ω not being available cannot be an excuse. There is always copy & paste.

Comment: @glglgl There are file formats and programs that can only store 8bit characters in strings, and don't support code tables apart from the system code table. Copy & paste into these file formats or programs will produce anything but legible greek characters (except maybe on a greek computer system).

Comment: @Alexander That's another thing than not having it on the keyboard. Although, in 2016, programs behaving this way should be considered buggy and incomplete.

Comment: @glglgl As programmers, we consider them "legacy" like two-digit year numbers.

Comment: @glglgl you would be surprised how much very old legacy code is running in current (and very expensive) CAD software...

Comment: @glglgl: Incomplete yes, buggy no.  When one considers the cost of support for non-ASCII characters in a schematic entry program, compared to features that are directly related to circuit design, one can see why such a thing may be way down the priority list.

Comment: @Alexander: Not only that, but many CAD programs use one or more sets of hard-coded stroked-character shapes, rather than using system fonts, and thus cannot use any characters which are not in their hard-coded set regardless of how many system fonts include it.

Comment: @supercat Ok, that's indeed a valid point.

Comment: @glglgl The only somewhat widely used 7/8-bit character set that [defines a capital omega](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a9/charset_support.htm) is [ISO-8859-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7), and even that is relatively uncommon compared to US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, Mac OS Roman, etc. You would certainly encounter rendering issues in software without Unicode support. In 8859-1 0xD9 isn't defined, in Windows-1252 it's a Ù, in Mac OS Roman it's Ÿ.

Comment: *"less easy to misread"* - Adding to this, worth noting that different locale's decimal separators (point vs. comma) could make things very tricky when, say, manufacturing a pcb / publishing schematics then making them available globally.

Comment: @JasonC "rendering issues in software without Unicode support" But IF the software has Unicode support, it isn't a point anymore, that was my point. And if it hasn't, it is legacy, broken or both. But there are valid points such as the stroked-character shapes, which have convinced me. (Although there should be more or less complete fonts even for this shape.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Even if it is way down the prority list: Unicode exists since 1991, UTF-8 since 1998. That's 25 resp. 18 years. In such a long time, one could have fixed such things. OTOH, people are accustomed now to writing R for Ω and uF fur µF.

Comment: @glglgl You appear to be making a point about something very inconsequential, unless you are lobbying for some sort of global movement away from "R" and towards "Ω" (not sure what problem that would solve though) - in which case this is not the most effective place to start. Electronics aren't broken because people are writing Rs everywhere. I think it's going to be OK.

Comment: @JasonC I am not lobbying at all – I just am sometimes annoyed by software (in general) which, in 2016, still doesn't cope well with Unicode. That's indeed nothing which can be solved here, was meant as a "side-comment" and has now grown to an extended discussion which essentially serves to nothing. The sentence I was referring to was __The current use of 'R' would then be excused (4R7 instead of 4Ω7) on the basis that Ω isn't readily available on most keyboards.__ which isn't the point – it is not the keyboard whihc is the problem.

Comment: @transistor Adding to this answer: The use of R (as well as the other letters) is standardized in BS 1852 and it's successors. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1852).

Comment: @glglgl: "_...  it is not the keyboard **whihc** is the problem._" Ha ha!

Comment: Thanks for discussing capacitor-nomenclatures also. some resistors and capacitors are so tiny . Abbreviations probably helpful for alphanumeric coding. Some resistors and most capacitors are alphanumeric coded. however capacitor alphanumeric-codes often contains decimal points I've seen so-many times.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: Yes, but none of the others asked specifically about 100R. I might do a question for each of the E12 series to earn some extra rep. What do you think? ;^)

Comment: @Transistor sorry I've misplaced the comment . They were to be under the original question. I thought link them up would help the readers find similar-discussion. As well, so-many possible duplicates prove this is a very common problem which is often not  explained clearly.

Answer (score 16):

It is quite common to see the letter "R" used as a decimal point. As in **47R9** = 47.9 ohms. And likewise, it is common to see the letter "K" or "M".  For example **6K81** would be 6,810 ohms and **2M3** would be 2,300,000 ohms.

Comment: So in this case it just means 100.0 ?

Comment: Yes. 100R means 100 ohms.

Comment: You may also see 6R8 or 2R2 on an inductor to represent 6.8uH or 2.2uH respectively.

Comment: It makes sense that they use R as a decimal point as if they actually printed a decimal point on a piece of paper, it could be easily be misread due to its small size or be rubbed out.

Comment: Alternatively, if it was *common* to use a decimal point on parts, you might confuse a speck of dust (or a manufacturing flaw) between two digits as a decimal point.

Comment: And remember that the comma and period (aka "dot" or "full-stop") mean opposite things on either side of the Atlantic.  "R" is arguably more universal.  Does the letter represent "Resistance" or "Radix"?  Who knows?

Answer (score 13):

Adding to the other answers, sometimes you may even see E used in place of R. So a 100 ohm resistor would be 100E and a 9.1 ohm resistor would be 9E1 for example.

Comment: I've never seen E used as a place holder for a decimal point, "R", "k", "m" and "M" obviously for resistors and "m", "u", "n", "f"and "p"on capacitors and inductors.  Where is "E" used in this way? You some times see E used in scientific notation so for example \$1\text{E}3 = 1 \times 10^3 \$ but not on circuit diagrams.

Comment: Here's a link to a component supplier where E is used extensively. http://www.mantech.co.za/Stock.aspx?Query=1Eand

Comment: It may not be very common but if anyone ever comes across a schematic with E instead of R this answer may help them.

Comment: Why down vote my answer? You can legitimately come across the E notation in Africa.

Comment: @bitshift, I think the people who downvote you have never heard of this, so they downvote because they think you are wrong. I did not downvote you. But I have never heard of this before. I did click on the link you provided, and, indeed, E seems to be used. Learn something new every day.

Comment: I have heard of it many times and subsequently upvoted it to not drive away users from this site.

Comment: Same here, never seen E-marks, but R-marks are quite common.

Comment: This answer is not helpful unless it clarifies whether `E` is being used for scientific notation in these listings, or as a direct analogue for `R`.  I suspect it is the former, that 9E1 is a 90 ohm resistor, while 9R1 is a 9.1 ohm.

Comment: @BenVoigt No 90 ohm would be 90E but I've expanded my answer to try and make it more clear.

Comment: Philips do this extensively. An oscilloscope service manual I have in front of me right now has for example `7E5`, `100E`, `1k`, `7k5`, `51k1`, etc.

Comment: @bitshift You should add the example link (and pipe's comment above) into the answer in case these comments get cleaned up.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I would note that perhaps downvoters are doing so because while this is interesting and potentially useful, *it doesn't actually answer the question that was asked*.  Perhaps you should post this as a question and then self-answer it, and a comment here could make it a linked question?

Comment: Is E the first letter of the word for resistance in some language, perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

Typically, resistor "multipliers" are represented as:

**KΩ** (thousands of ohms),

**MΩ** (millions of ohms),

**GΩ** (thousands of millions of ohms)
...etc.

Since the context usually makes it clear that we're talking about resistor values, it's common short-hand to drop the 'Ω' so that, for example, you can write "39K"* instead of "39KΩ".
But, dropping the "Ω" leaves the problem of how to represent a resistor value when the multiplier is 1.
So it was decided that "R" would represent a "x1" multiplier.  So now you can write "39R" instead of "39Ω".

The multipliers (R, K, M, G... etc) can also be used as shorthand for decimal points.
So, for example, instead of having to write "2.2Ω", you can simply write "2R2".
All the multipliers can be used in this way.  A final example: "3.3KΩ" can be written as "3K3"

*Note that it is common practice to capitalise the "K" multiplier when referring to resistor values.  Technically this is incorrect, as "k" is the official '1000' prefix.  But it's just a shorthand, limited in its use to **resistor** values, and the capital K is in common use in this context.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42779/discussion-on-answer-by-q-what-is-a-100r-resistor).

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia tells,

> The notation to state a resistor's value in a circuit diagram varies. The **European notation [BS 1852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1852)** avoids using **a decimal separator**, and replaces the decimal separator with the **SI prefix symbol** for the particular value. For example, **8k2** in a circuit diagram indicates a resistor value of **8.2 kΩ**. Additional zeros imply tighter tolerance, for example **15M0**. When the value can be expressed without the need for an SI prefix, an **"R"** is used instead of the decimal separator. For example, **1R2** indicates **1.2 Ω**, and **18R** indicates **18 Ω**. The use of a SI prefix symbol or the letter **"R"** circumvents the problem that decimal separators tend to **"disappear"** when **photocopying** a printed circuit diagram.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Electronic_symbols_and_notation

Also, I've seen, 1. just-like R, also **E** is being used such as **4E7** etc. 
2. the zero for tighter-tolerance sometimes not given, such as 47K, 56K etc.