# What does an "E" mean in a resistor value? (ie 150E)

Tags: resistors

I'm trying to build a dc motor controller circuit as described [here](http://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/86517-build-a-dc-motor-speed-controller-circuit/).

But it requires 2 "150E" resistors

From looking online I believe this means 15 ohms but I'm curious as to why, and why I couldn't find anywhere explaining such.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bloated site, could at least have posted a pic of where this info shows up. Providing context helps most of the times..

Comment: Also see [this specific answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/246932/) to the related topic "What is a 100R resistor?" which discusses "E" being used in a similar way to "R".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

E means ohms. 150E is 150 ohm.

See [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251598/what-does-it-mean-that-a-resistor-has-value-of-56e/251600#251600)

Comment: No it doesn't. E most likely stands for an E series resistor e.g. E24 - preferred value resistor see http://www.resistorguide.com/resistor-values/

Comment: E24, yes. 150E on the other hand means 150 ohm. There is no E150 series.

Comment: I stand corrected - you can get a 2E2 resistor (2.2 ohms) so +1

Comment: @JImDearden No problem. My far fetched theory behind the usage of E instead of R when limited to 25 letters, a few signs and numbers would be that an E turned 90 degrees looks like a small omega. Someone hopefully have a real answer or better theory. Perhaps some old CAD system?

Comment: Maybe because it has something to do with ~E~lectrons? he..he..

Comment: Best I've come up with - the letter E in Morse is "."

Comment: @JImDearden Brilliant!

Comment: @JImDearden  I think the common decimal pt. abbreviation in Morse code is "R". Never have heard an "E" used this way, but can confirm that "R" is used surrounded by numbers.

Comment: Or maybe it could be similar to 2E2 meaning 2*10^2. So 150E means 150*10^0 = 150.

Comment: @FreezingFire 2E2 I would interpret as 2.2 ohm but I’ve never seen it in use.